# Parameter in request of Elasticsearch using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, post, elasticsearch

Can we passe a parameter in that request ? query :p

```
client.search({
index: 'name_index',
type: 'name_type',

body: {
  query: {
  filtered: {
  query: {
      query_string: {
      query:  p ,
      analyze_wildcard: true
    }
  } }
 ....

}

}
```

Help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What is p? Is it a query string parameter? You need `name:value` to use `query_string`.

Comment: p can be for example John or ronaldo or katy , that a value a want to make as parameter , is it possible?

Comment: but what field do you expect John or ronaldo or katy to appear in?